# When I select the incorrect answer the next question loads with the answer already displayed

Tags: c#, winforms, linq

I am completely new to coding and c#. I am studying level 3 ICT and in my programming subject, we are asked to make a quiz for essential skills students(Using forms.). 
I have been asked to create a very basic login in screen, topic selection screen, level selection screen, and the actual questions and answers; answers are buttons.

My issue is when I select the incorrect answer to the next question loads but displays the correct answer to that question.

Not quite sure what I need to do. I wanted to get this fixed over the weekend so I am unable to ask my teacher.

The must remain very basic.

Here is my code. I appreciate any help on this topic.

Level 0 Form -

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace EssentialSkills.Numeracy
{
    public partial class Level0num : Form
    {
        Point p1 = new Point(142, 303);
        Point p2 = new Point(322, 303);
        Point p3 = new Point(499, 303);
        List<Point> points = new List<Point>();


        public Level0num()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Globals.listQuestionsNum0.Add("1 + 1");
            Globals.listQuestionsNum0.Add("9 x 1");
            Globals.listQuestionsNum0.Add("10 x 3");
            Globals.listQuestionsNum0.Add("3 / 3");
            Globals.listQuestionsNum0.Add("2 + 5 + 6");
            Globals.listQuestionsNum0.Add("8 x 3");
            Globals.listQuestionsNum0.Add("99 - 87");
            Globals.listQuestionsNum0.Add("60 + 10 ");
            Globals.listQuestionsNum0.Add("55 + 15");
            Globals.listQuestionsNum0.Add("40 x 20");
            Globals.listQuestionsNum0.Add("120 / 60");
            Globals.listQuestionsNum0.Add("1.0 + 1.2");
            Globals.listQuestionsNum0.Add("3 x 13");
            Globals.listQuestionsNum0.Add("2 x 2");
            Globals.listQuestionsNum0.Add("10 x 30");
            Globals.listQuestionsNum0.Add("8 x 9");
            Globals.listQuestionsNum0.Add("9 x 9");
            Globals.listQuestionsNum0.Add("3 x 1");
            Globals.listQuestionsNum0.Add("4 / 4");
            Globals.listQuestionsNum0.Add("21 / 7");
            Globals.listQuestionsNum0.Add("42 / 7");
            Globals.listQuestionsNum0.Add("10 + 10 - 1");
            Globals.listQuestionsNum0.Add("84 - 2 + 3");
            Globals.listQuestionsNum0.Add("50 + 9 + 8");
            Globals.listQuestionsNum0.Add("-1 + 2");
            Globals.listQuestionsNum0.Add("33 + 88");
            Globals.listQuestionsNum0.Add("10 - 3");
            Globals.listQuestionsNum0.Add("32 + 2 x 1");
            Globals.listQuestionsNum0.Add("1 x 543 + 1");
            Globals.listQuestionsNum0.Add("3 + 10 x 2");

            Globals.listAnswersNum0.Add(1 + 1);
            Globals.listAnswersNum0.Add(9 * 1);
            Globals.listAnswersNum0.Add(10 * 3);
            Globals.listAnswersNum0.Add(3 / 3);
            Globals.listAnswersNum0.Add(2 + 5 + 6);
            Globals.listAnswersNum0.Add(8 * 3);
            Globals.listAnswersNum0.Add(99 - 87);
            Globals.listAnswersNum0.Add(60 + 10);
            Globals.listAnswersNum0.Add(55 + 15);
            Globals.listAnswersNum0.Add(40 * 20);
            Globals.listAnswersNum0.Add(120 / 60);
            Globals.listAnswersNum0.Add(1.0 + 1.2);
            Globals.listAnswersNum0.Add(3 * 13);
            Globals.listAnswersNum0.Add(2 * 2);
            Globals.listAnswersNum0.Add(10 * 30);
            Globals.listAnswersNum0.Add(8 * 9);
            Globals.listAnswersNum0.Add(9 * 9);
            Globals.listAnswersNum0.Add(3 * 1);
            Globals.listAnswersNum0.Add(4 / 4);
            Globals.listAnswersNum0.Add(21 / 7);
            Globals.listAnswersNum0.Add(42 / 7);
            Globals.listAnswersNum0.Add(10 + 10 - 1);
            Globals.listAnswersNum0.Add(84 - 2 + 3);
            Globals.listAnswersNum0.Add(50 + 9 + 8);
            Globals.listAnswersNum0.Add(-1 + 2);
            Globals.listAnswersNum0.Add(33 + 88);
            Globals.listAnswersNum0.Add(10 - 3);
            Globals.listAnswersNum0.Add(32 + 2 * 1);
            Globals.listAnswersNum0.Add(1 * 543 * 1);
            Globals.listAnswersNum0.Add(3 + 10 * 2);

            points.Add(p1);
            points.Add(p2);
            points.Add(p3);


        }
        private void LoadQuestions()
        {
            lblCountdownval.Visible = false;
            lblCountdown.Visible = false;


            Globals.intQuestionNumber += 1;
            lblQuestionsNumber.Text = "Question Number: " + Globals.intQuestionNumber.ToString();


            Random random = new Random();
            Globals.listIndex = random.Next(0, Globals.listAnswersNum0.Count - 1);
            lblQuestion.Text = Globals.listQuestionsNum0.ElementAt(Globals.listIndex);
            btnCorrect.Text = Globals.listAnswersNum0.ElementAt(Globals.listIndex).ToString();
            btnAnswer1.Text = random.Next(100).ToString();
            btnAnswer3.Text = random.Next(100).ToString();

            int locationIndex = random.Next(0, 3);
            btnCorrect.Location = points.ElementAt(locationIndex);

            locationIndex = random.Next(0, 3);

            btnAnswer1.Location = points.ElementAt(locationIndex);
            while ((btnAnswer1.Location == btnCorrect.Location))
            {
                locationIndex = random.Next(0, 3);
                btnAnswer1.Location = points.ElementAt(locationIndex);

            }
            locationIndex = random.Next(0, 3);
            btnAnswer3.Location = points.ElementAt(locationIndex);

            while ((btnAnswer3.Location == btnCorrect.Location) || (btnAnswer3.Location == btnAnswer1.Location))
            {
                locationIndex = random.Next(0, 3);
                btnAnswer3.Location = points.ElementAt(locationIndex);
            }
        }

        public void showCorrectAnswer()
        { 
            timerLoadQuestion.Start();
            lblCountdownval.Visible = true;
            lblCountdown.Visible = true;
            lblCountdownval.Text = "5";
            lblCountdown.Text = "Next question will load in .... ";

            btnAnswer1.Visible = false;
            btnAnswer3.Visible = false;
            btnCorrect.Location = p2;
            btnCorrect.BackColor = Color.Green;

        }

        private void Level0num_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lblLoggedUser.Text = Globals.loggedUser;

            lblQuestionsNumber.Text = "Question Number: ";
            LoadQuestions();

            Globals.s = 0;
            lblScore.Text = "Score: " + Globals.s;

        }

        private void btnBack_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            frmNumeracy back = new frmNumeracy();
            this.Close();
            back.ShowDialog();
        }

        private void btnAnswer1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            showCorrectAnswer();
            MessageBox.Show("Incorrect");
            LoadQuestions();

        }

        private void btnAnswer3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            showCorrectAnswer();
            MessageBox.Show("Incorrect");
            LoadQuestions();

        }

        private void btnCorrect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Correct!");

            Globals.s += 1;
            lblScore.Text = "Score: " + Globals.s.ToString();
            LoadQuestions();
        }
    }
}
```

here is my globals class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace EssentialSkills
{
    public static class Globals
    {
        public static string username, password;

        public static string user1, user2, user3, user4, user5, user6, loggedUser, admin;
        public static string pass1, pass2, pass3, pass4, pass5, pass6, adminPass1;

        public static List<string> listQuestionsNum0 = new List<string>();
        public static List<double> listAnswersNum0 = new List<double>();

        public static int intQuestionNumber = 0;

        public static int listIndex;

        public static int s;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it's hard to say exactly since the code you pasted is not enough to duplicate it on my end, but just from a quick scan through, it seems like you are relying on a lot of state (e.g. button locations/positions, colors, visibility, etc) to be kept within each of the controls on the main form. Since the form is not being re-created for each question, there is most likely some assumption in your initialization for the 1st question that's not getting explicitly set properly for the 2nd question (and subsequent questions).

So, for example, if you set btnCorrect.BackColor to green for a successful answer, make sure to re-initialize it back to red (or whatever the default values is in your form) for the next question (e.g. in LoadQuestions()).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Anything I can to help you copy this code and you’re telling me to set the colour values of the buttons back to white(default) at the end of loadQuestions()?

Comment: Also my there is supposed to be a timer which counts down how long the question stays on screen then moves onto the next one. A feature which doesn’t seem to work.